# Export excel file with macro saved in it

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, export

I have a vba function in access that runs some SQL commands and at the end exports one of the tables to excel.  I was wondering if there was a way to save a macro in the excel spreadsheet when it exports it? I posted the line of code below that exports the table:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "PDFVerified", "Rev-H"
```

Comment: This may be possible, by enabling programmatic access to the VBA object model (VBE) and importing a code module into the exported workbook.

Comment: How would I do the first part?

Comment: That would be in the Macro Security settings

Comment: Ok, then how would I import the module through VBA?

Comment: Depends where your macro is...

Comment: It is in my access database..

Comment: A really simple solution is to create an empty Excel workbook that already has your macro. Let that be your template.

Answer (score 0):

As retailcoder stated first enable programmatic access to project by checking the box at Options->TrustCenter->TrustCenterSettings->MacroSettings->TrustAccessToTheVBAProjectObjectModel. Then import the module with

```
ExcelWorkbookObject.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "ModuleAddressAndName"
```